# Roundcube config script not found by Apache

Tags: apache2, postfix, roundcube

I have installed roundcube and roundcube-psql on Ubuntu 20.04 from the packages.  At the top of /etc/apache2/conf-available/roundcube.conf there is a single alias which I have uncommented.

```
# Uncomment them to use it or adapt them to your configuration
Alias /roundcube /var/lib/roundcube
```

After reloading Apache, the login screen works in a browser when I load http://ipaddress/roundcube, but the /usr/share/roundcube/installer/config.php file cannot be found by http://ipaddress/roundcube/installer/config.php.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Roundcube says there should be two alias lines to uncomment, but in the latest source code of Roundcube there's only one alias.

How do I fix this so that I can run the config.php script?

Update:

Roundcube is installed into /usr/share/roundcube, but there are symlinks in /var/lib/roundcube as below:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   14 Feb 24  2020 config -> /etc/roundcube
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   30 Feb 24  2020 index.php -> /usr/share/roundcube/index.php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   19 Feb 24  2020 logs -> ../../log/roundcube
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 21 17:16 plugins
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   28 Feb 24  2020 program -> /usr/share/roundcube/program
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 21 17:16 skins
drwxr-x--- 2 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 24  2020 temp
```

There's index.php linking to /usr/share/roundcube/index.php, but not to the setup scripts. So I added the following symlink:

```
installer -> /usr/share/roundcube/installer
```

This allows the installer to run, but on the "create config" step, nothing is generated, so clearly there are more missing links ;-)

This seems like a bug in the package to me.  Why create symlinks in /var/lib/roundcube in the first place?

Comment: Was RoundCube installed into `/var/lib/roundcube`? This is a non-standard location and may require some changes to the AppArmor configuration, as Apache is not permitted to read outside of `/var/www` by default 

Comment: I updated the question to show more details